# JSP Buttons and Selects doesn't work as expected after switching to bootstrap

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp

The Update and Delete buttons are not working as expected in index.jsp when using bootstrap. Also the `OnClick` doesn't work either. OnClick() function exits in `Script` block.

Any idea how to fix this?

Here is the index.jsp code without bootstrap..

```
        <td><td><label >Select Storage Type</label></td></td>
        <td>
            <form:select  name= "storageType" path="storageType" onchange="submit()">
                <form:option value="session"  >Session</form:option>
                <form:option value="database" >Database</form:option>
            </form:select>
        </td>
```

And the rows

```
    <table>
        <c:forEach items="${accountListWrapper.accountList}" varStatus="i" var="account">
            <tr>
                <td><label >Iban</label></td>
                <!-- if response is not from database account.id should be null -->
                <td><form:input  id="${account.id==null ? i.index:account.id}iban" path="accountList[${i.index}].iban" /></td>
                <td><label >Business Identifier Code</label></td>
                <td><form:input  id="${account.id==null ? i.index:account.id}businessIdentifierCode" path="accountList[${i.index}].businessIdentifierCode" /></td>
                <td><button onclick="updateRow(${account.id==null ? i.index:account.id})" />Update</td>
                <td><button onclick="deleteRow(${account.id==null ? i.index:account.id})" />Delete</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

[image]

I'm trying to achieve the same in bootstrap but the buttons doesn't work.

```
                                <form:form method="GET" modelAttribute="accountListWrapper"
                                    action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/">
                                    <div class="form-row">
                                        <label class="col-form-label">Select Storage Type</label>
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <form:select class="form-control " data-width="100%" id="selectStorageType" name="storageType"
                                                path="storageType" onchange="submit()">
                                                <form:option value="session">Session</form:option>
                                                <form:option value="database">Database</form:option>
                                            </form:select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <c:forEach items="${accountListWrapper.accountList}" varStatus="i" var="account">
                                        <div class=form-row>

                                            <label for="Iban" class="col-form-label">Iban</label>
                                            <div class="col">
                                                <form:input id="${account.id==null ? i.index:account.id}iban" type="text"
                                                    class="form-control " name="accountList[${i.index}].iban"
                                                    path="accountList[${i.index}].iban" placeholder="1234567896454" />
                                            </div>
                                            <label for="BIC" class="col-form-label  text-center">Business Identifier Code</label>
                                            <div class="col">
                                                <form:input id="${account.id==null ? i.index:account.id}businessIdentifierCode" type="text"
                                                    class="form-control " name="accountList[${i.index}].businessIdentifierCode"
                                                    path="accountList[${i.index}].businessIdentifierCode" placeholder="1234567896454" />
                                            </div>

                                            <button class="input-group-append btn btn-info btn-sm m-1"
                                                onclick="updateRow(${account.id==null ? i.index:account.id})" type="button">Update</button>

                                            <button class="input-group-append btn btn-info btn-sm m-1"
                                                onclick="deleteRow(${account.id==null ? i.index:account.id})" type="button">Delete</button>
                                            <br>
                                        </div>
                                    </c:forEach>



                                    <div class=form-row>
                                        <label for="Iban" class="col-form-label">Iban</label>
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <input id="createIban" class="form-control" placeholder="createIban" />
                                        </div>
                                        <label for="Iban" class="col-form-label">Business Identifier Code</label>
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <input id="createBusinessIdentifierCode" class="form-control width100"
                                                placeholder="createBusinessIdentifierCode" />
                                        </div>
                                        <button class="input-group-append btn btn-info btn-sm m-1" onclick="createRow()"
                                            type="button">Create</button>
                                    </div>

                                </form:form>
```

[image]

The Script block:

```
                            <script>
    function updateRow(index) {
        const contextPath= "${pageContext.request.contextPath}";
        storageTypeUrl= $('select[name=storageType]').val() == "session"  ? "sessionOperations" : "operations";
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "PUT",
            url: contextPath+"/"+storageTypeUrl+"/?index="+index+"&iban="+document.getElementById(index+"iban").value
            +"&businessIdentifierCode="+document.getElementById(index+"businessIdentifierCode").value,
            success: function(data){
                console.log("update Row successful");
            },
            error : function(request,error) {
                alert(error);
            }});
    }
    function createRow() {      
        const contextPath= "${pageContext.request.contextPath}";
        storageTypeUrl= $('select[name=storageType]').val() == "session"  ? "sessionOperations" : "operations";
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: contextPath+"/"+storageTypeUrl+"/?iban="+document.getElementById("createIban").value
            +"&businessIdentifierCode="+document.getElementById("createBusinessIdentifierCode").value,
            success: function(data){
                console.log("create Row successful");
            },
            error : function(request,error) {
                alert(error);
            }});
    }
    function deleteRow(index,id) {
        const contextPath= "${pageContext.request.contextPath}";
        storageTypeUrl= $('select[name=storageType]').val() == "session"  ? "sessionOperations" : "operations";
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "DELETE",
            url: contextPath+"/"+storageTypeUrl+"/?index="+index,
            success: function(data){
                console.log("delete Row successful");
            },
            error : function(request,error) {
                alert(error);
            }});
    }
</script>
```

In the old jsp code, the url when click update or delete changes the URL as follows.
http://localhost:8080/?storageType=session&accountList[0].iban=123&accountList[0].businessIdentifierCode=123

But after bootstrap it changes as follows and it prints console.log which doesn't happen in old jsp code and if we keep clicking the buttons then `IndexOutOfBounds` exception happens.

http://localhost:8080/sessionOperations/?index=0&iban=initIban&businessIdentifierCode=initBusinessIdentifierCode

Error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:659)
    at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:450)
    at com.apiDemo.controller.BanksSessionController.update(BanksSessionController.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:879)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. I just had to remove the `type="button"` from all buttons and it started working.